# C++ socket programming: packing data from an array of different types

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm new to socket programming in C++, and while I do have the basics down, I'm having trouble tackling the following situation:

I have a function which consumes an array of void pointers (i.e. void **). Each pointer will be pointing to a different standard C data type (i.e. char, int, short, long, float, double). This array will be of variable length, but I will have access to its length and the type of data each pointer is pointing to.

The goal of this function is to send all the data pointed to by the pointers. My question is: is there a way to send this all in one go?

By the way, I do know that send() doesn't guarantee the delivery of every byte. I do have a helper function which loops and invokes send() as many times as needed. My question has to do with packing and serializing the data.

If I want to send an integer, I simply invoke htons() or htonl() in order to convert the data to network byte order.

If I want to send a variable length string, I simply send the length of the string first followed by the actual string. Easy enough.

But what if I want to send a variable amount of data, all in one go (assuming I have my helper to guarantee the delivery of every byte), where the data comes from an array of pointers to different C standard data types? Again, I know I'll want to send the length of the data first, which is no problem because I do know the length and the type of each pointer in the array. I just don't know how to pack it to ensure that it'll be in network byte order.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Please specify whether you are using C or C++.

Comment: Thank you for stating the obvious. My question is related to socket programming, which is similar in C and C++. Besides, I mentioned C only because my array has pointers of standard C types.

Comment: It just saves hassle for answerers when you indicate which language you're going to be compiling for.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited my post.

Comment: You want to read about Marshalling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and Serialisation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).